# asp.net display login form for only for anonymous users

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a login form in my header of master page that always displays no matter if im logged in or out. How can I change it to shows only to annonymous users ?

I tried like this

```
<asp:LoginView ID="Loginview1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <ul id="loginmeni">
            <ul>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox></ul>
            <ul>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox></ul>
            <ul>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="buttonlogin" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /></ul>
            <a href="#">Zaboravljena sifra</a>
        </ul>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <a href="#">Logout</a>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

And this is on click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txtusername.Text !="" || txtpassword.Text !="")
    {

        Vlasnici v= ServisnaKlasa.VratiVlasnika(txtusername.Text.Trim(),txtpassword.Text.Trim());
        if(v !=null)
        {
            loginsesija.v = v;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tiket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(v.VlasnikID.ToString(), false, 30);
            string enTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tiket);
            HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, enTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(v.VlasnikID.ToString(),false));
        }
        else
        {
            txtusername.Text = "";
            Response.Write("jebiga");
        }
    }
}
```

I get error when try to loggin

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and also now it doesnt even recognize those textfields "txtusername" and "txtpassword"

heres the error

> Error 4   The name 'txtusername' does not exist in the current context    D:\PeP Projekat\Web dio\WebApplication10\main.Master.cs 23  16  IS_VeterinarskaStanicaWebDio

Comment: Add the master page directive and the .cs page namespace.

Comment: Found a solution with wrapping the asp controls with <% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>